# datetime format in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have used below code to convert a datetime to string,

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '08/07/2015 12:10 AM'
set @StartDate = dateadd(hour,12, @StartDate);

select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@StartDate, 101) + RIGHT(STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32),     @StartDate,100), 18, 0, ' '),8)
```

but I am getting output as "08/07/201512:10 PM" , there is no space between date and time, How can I correct this?

Comment: Instead of using a localized format (is that July 8 or August 7 ?), use an one of the invariant literal, ie the ISO 8601 format for full dates (eg `20150707T00:10:00`) or the unseparated format for dates only (eg `20150708`). You *don't* need to use strange conversions to enter a date literal. If you find yourself doing so, you are doing something wrong

Comment: Is it August 7th or July 8th?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, its August 7th

Comment: It is recommended that formatting (including date formatting) is handled at the UI level instead of the database level. The reason it's so hard to do in SQL is that SQL isn't intended to do your formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i correctly understood your problem then there is small correction required in your code. I added  +' '+ i.e. a blank space between your date convert and right stuff. Complete code is as given below.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '08/07/2015 12:10 AM'
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(HOUR,12, @StartDate);

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@StartDate, 101) +' '+
RIGHT(STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32),@StartDate,100), 18, 0, ' '),8)
```

Result

```
08/07/2015 12:10 PM
```

i.e. space between date and time also space between 12:10 and PM

To cover new case provided :

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '08/07/2015 2:10 AM'
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(HOUR,12, @StartDate);

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@StartDate, 101) +' '+
LTRIM(RIGHT(STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32),@StartDate,100), 18, 0, ' '),8))
```

Result

```
08/07/2015 2:10 PM
```

i.e. no extra space when time is like 2:10 PM

Comment: if the time is 2:10 PM, then we get one more space between the date and time

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2015-08-07T00:10:00';

SET @StartDate = dateadd(hour,12, @StartDate);

SELECT  @StartDate As StartDate,
        CONVERT(CHAR(10), @StartDate, 101) + ' ' + --  DateString,
        SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR(19), @StartDate, 100), 13, 5) + ' ' + -- TimeString
        RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(19), @StartDate, 100), 2) As DateString -- AM/PM
```

Result:

```
StartDate                   DateString
-----------------------     -------------------
2015-08-07 12:10:00.000     08/07/2015 12:10 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet will produce the output you've indicated in the question.

```
SET DATEFORMAT MDY;

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '08-07-2015 12:10 AM';
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(HOUR, 12, @StartDate);

SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR, @StartDate, 103) + ' ' +
        CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(@StartDate AS TIME), 108) +
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, @StartDate) < 12 THEN ' AM' ELSE ' PM' END;
```

N.B. As others have pointed out, you would be better off using ISO format for input dates.

Updated dateformat from `DMY` to `MDY` and explicitly adding AM/PM to the end.

Comment: its result is "08/07/2015 12:10PM" there is no space between 12:10 and PM,